# Can i use text-align inside div by pixel?

Tags: html, css, text-align

Is there any way that i can align the text inside a `div` but without using `text-align`. I dont want to align it to a specific  position(center,left etc) but i want to align it where ever i want by pixel.For example between the values center and left. Also i dont want to use another element inside `div`.

I am looking something like that:

HTML

```
<div id="div">TEXT</div>
```

CSS

```
 #div{
    text-align:220px;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: padding-left should do that..

Comment: There's quite a few options you could take, `margins` (My perferred), `padding`, encase it with span and `position` it relatively.. etc

Comment: Did you try playing with `padding` ?

Comment: Could you clarify if `220px` means that you want the text left-aligned at 220 pixels from the left edge?

Comment: @laaposto Great—in that case, one of the answers below should work fine. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `margin` or `padding` to align the text, they will increase the size of your element as well, if you are aware of the CSS box model behavior, so if you are aligning them using `padding` or `margin` make sure you use the below

```
div {
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Though above will count the `margin` outside but will consider the `padding` and `border` inside the element.

Also, if you are looking to align only a single word, than better use `text-indent` property which will indent your text to a specific `px` you define.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LvhTs/)

But this will just indent 1st line so if you have a single word than this will suffice your needs, but if you want to align multiple elements, than the best thing to do here is to use `span` for each word and than indent it using `padding`

Answer (score 23):

Are you looking for `text-indent` ?

```
#div{
  text-indent: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can not, `text-align` gives a **general behavior for the text to align** as opposed to  `px` which is a **measuring unit**, also, logically speaking....`220px` wont tell browser, which side of screen 220px is referring to....
i'll suggest using `<p>` or `<span>` instead

```
#div > span, #div > p{
     /*some margin or padding like
     margin-left : 220px;
     padding-left : 220px;
    */
    }
```

**EDIT**

To avoid a `tag` inside `div`, use :

```
div#cont {
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    padding-left:150px; /*left-right-top-bottom-depend on ur choice*/
    border:1px solid #000;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**solution demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/YsjW5/3/)

Comment: Also i dont want to use another element inside div